# What is difference between USB external enclosure and SATA-to-USB cable?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure

There are SATA-to-USB cables and there are USB external enclosure that allows USB access to SATA drives. But what are differences? Is this matter of just having casing, or is there something like interface in an external enclosure?

Comment: Both have an interface (usb to sata chip), both accomplish the same thing.

Comment: For a 2.5" drive, there should be no electrical difference.  For a 3.5" drive, the enclosure should have appropriate power capability, whereas you're on your own power-wise with the USB-to-SATA adapter.